# Life Cycle Exception

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, module, liferay

I get `Life Cycle Exception` when I try to run a `liferay 7 module` on a server.I use `eclipse luna ide`,`liferay 7.0 ga3`, `tomcat server 8.0.32`.All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You're going to need to post a lot more information. Let's start with the stack trace if you can get it. Also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is too little information here. Could you paste here the entire stack trace that has this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I the 8005 port that was needed by tomcat server was used by another application, I do not know exactly which one, but now I don't have the problem anymore, you can change that default port.